# Why is this ptvsd package failing to compile?

Tags: python-3.x, yocto, pypi, bitbake

I'm using [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) to compile a custom Linux environment, and I have created a recipe for a python package my team wants called [ptvsd](https://pypi.org/project/ptvsd/).  This package allows for remote python debugging from Visual Studio.

I have created the recipe and everything seems to be working until somewhere in the package compilation process (do_package).  I get the following error:

```
ERROR: python3-ptvsd-4.3.2-r0 do_package: objcopy failed with exit code 1 (cmd was 'aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy' --only-keep-debug '/home/build/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-ptvsd/4.3.2-r0/package/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_linux_amd64.so' '/home/build/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-ptvsd/4.3.2-r0/package/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process/.debug/attach_linux_amd64.so'):
aarch64-poky-linux-objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `/home/build/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-ptvsd/4.3.2-r0/package/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process/attach_linux_amd64.so'
ERROR: python3-ptvsd-4.3.2-r0 do_package: Function failed: split_and_strip_files
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/build/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/python3-ptvsd/4.3.2-r0/temp/log.do_package.7857
ERROR: Task (/home/build/var-fsl-yocto/sources/meta-freeport/recipes-all/python3-ptvsd/python3-ptvsd_4.3.2.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
```

I had added a couple lines to my recipe based on posts I saw from people having similar problems, but neither of them helped, and I've since removed them:

```
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
do_package_qa[noexec] = "1"
```

Here is my recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "The Python Visual Studio Debugger engine implements the Visual Studio Code debug protocol and is used as the debug engine in Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code."
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=188c79d3dc9cb6dee7269656ee30caa9"
PYPI_PACKAGE = "ptvsd"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "2daa111824de0f1384690916469f750c"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "3b05c06018fdbce5943c50fb0baac695b5c11326f9e21a5266c854306bda28ab"
PYPI_PACKAGE_EXT = "zip"

inherit pypi
```

It looks like the problem may have something to do with the shared object file in the package attach_linux_amd64.so, but I'm not sure.  Does anybody have some idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Wild guess: different architecture (I see `aarch64` in your question)?

Comment: Wow.  That seems very likely.  I'm 99% sure the package supports ARM, but I'm likely not pulling down the right architecture some how.  I'll have to look in to this.  Thanks!

Comment: I only see amd64 and x86 .so files in the package.  But I was sure we've used this on ARM before...

Comment: If you downloaded a wheel from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/ptvsd/#files) — PyPI only allows to upload binary wheels for Linux, MacOS X and Windows on Intel processors. Perhaps you've downloaded a wheel from [PiWheels](https://www.piwheels.org/project/ptvsd/) — it has wheels for Raspberry Pi and other ARM platforms.

Comment: The package I'm targeting is: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/0c/baf985198b25f32b3fb75cbf1a51689ca02f6f80039d3105211b92962e41/ptvsd-4.3.2.zip

Comment: That's sdist (source distribution) intended to be installed with `pip install` or even `python setup.py install`. Only source code (Python, Cython and C), no binaries. Source code (Cython and C) will be compiled during installation.

Comment: attach_linux_amd64.so seems to tell me that its not really cross compiling.  so something in this package is probably poking at build host to find architecture. Another issue could be that it generates attach .so for all arches, in this case you need to delete them in do_install and only package the one which pertains to this arch alone ( aarch64 )

Comment: As @Khem says it is not cross-compiling it. If you look at the sources here: https://github.com/microsoft/ptvsd/tree/master/src/ptvsd/_vendored/pydevd/pydevd_attach_to_process you see that the repo contains prebuilt binaries. But it also seems like the source is available under `linux_and_mac` so maybe you can compile your own versions and make that work.